# How to group sequential numbers separated by comma in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(50)= '07071318_G08(1,2,3,4,8,9,11)';
SELECT SUBSTRING(@a, CHARINDEX('(', @a) + 1, CHARINDEX(')', @a) - CHARINDEX('(', @a) - 1) as Val;
```

It gives the output as:

```
1,2,3,4,8,9,11
```

But I need to show the output as below:

```
1-4,8-9,11
```

It means I need to group sequential numbers if any together. Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: I am working on 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is the following statement, using `STRING_SPLIT()` (to split the comma-separated numbers), `ROW_NUMBER()` (to define the islands and gaps) and `CONCAT_WS()` and `STRING_AGG()` (for string aggregation):

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(50)= '07071318_G08(1,2,3,4,8,9,11)';

SELECT STRING_AGG([value], ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [rn]) AS [value]
FROM (
   SELECT MIN([value]) AS [rn], CONCAT_WS('-', MIN([value]), CASE WHEN MAX([value]) > MIN([value]) THEN MAX([value]) END) AS [value]
   FROM (
      SELECT 
         TRY_CONVERT(int, [value]) AS [value],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(int, [value])) AS [rn]
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(SUBSTRING(@a, CHARINDEX('(', @a) + 1, CHARINDEX(')', @a) - CHARINDEX('(', @a) - 1), ',')
   ) t1
   GROUP BY [value] - [rn]
) t2
```

Result:

```
value
1-4,8-9,11
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are on 2017, you get to use `string_agg()` , but first we perform a `Gaps-and-Islands`

**Example**

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(50)= '07071318_G08(1,2,3,4,8,9,11)';

Select MyNewString = string_agg(value,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY min_value )
 From (
        Select value=concat(min(value),IIF(min(value)=max(value),'',concat('-',max(value))))
              ,min_value = min(value)
         From (
                SELECT value = try_convert(int,value)
                      ,grp = value - row_number()  over(order by try_convert(int,value))
                 from string_split(SUBSTRING(@a, CHARINDEX('(', @a) + 1, CHARINDEX(')', @a) - CHARINDEX('(', @a) - 1),',')
              ) a
         Group by Grp 
       ) A
```

**Returns**

```
MyNewString
1-4,8-9,11
```

**Note:**  If duplicating values in the string like ...3,3,3... you may have to switch to `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()`

**EDIT - 2014 Version**

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(50)= '07071318_G08(1,2,3,4,8,9,11)';

Select NewValue = Stuff((Select ',' +NewValue
                          From (
                                Select NewValue = concat(min(RetVal),IIF(max(RetVal)=min(RetVal),'',concat('-',max(RetVal))))
                                      ,MinValue = min(RetVal)
                                 From (
                                        Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by try_convert(int,ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))))
                                              ,RetVal = try_convert(int,ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)'))))
                                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(SUBSTRING(@a, CHARINDEX('(', @a) + 1, CHARINDEX(')', @a) - CHARINDEX('(', @a) - 1),',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                                      ) a
                                 Group By RetVal-RetSeq    
                               ) a1
                           Order by MinValue
                          For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217507/discussion-on-answer-by-john-cappelletti-how-to-group-sequential-numbers-separat).